# Sending an encrypted parameter in Request to a .Net core WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

We are working on a web API which provides data to a xamarin app. I've been asked to send an encrypted parameter to the web API and use it to validate the request.What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Get more specific. Do you want to encrypt the data/value or just send a kind of hash tag which should help prevent the request from being forged or replayed?

Comment: You can make a custom AuthorizeAttribute and use it for your controller for validating your request.

Comment: So let's say the request class is customer I want to send a property EncryptedCustomerId. And when I receive it in the API I want to decrypt it. Since this property has to be sent with every request I'll probably create a base class and add this property in it

Comment: I don't want to add a header. I want to send the property in the request object

Comment: Why down vote it? It's a valid question. And I'm asking for the best way to do this. Even if it means not doing this and doing it in a diffway

Comment: It's a very open question, which is why it's being down voted. Best is subjective, and there are far too many ways to do encryption and validation. That's why I voted to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a custom Middleware to validate the encrypted parameter.